# Using Grub4Dos to Boot Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: grub4dos

How to configure Grub4dos to boot Ubuntu 16.04?

This is my command lines in menu.lst:

```
title Run Ubuntu 16.04 Server
find --set-root --ignore-floppies --ignore-cd /iso/ubuntu-16.04-server-amd64.iso
map --heads=0 --sectors-per-track=0 /iso/ubuntu-16.04-server-amd64.iso (hd32)
map --hook
chainloader (hd32)
```

I can boot the Installation of Ubuntu 16.04 Environment. But I think in step 4, the system says something like it tries to mount CD-ROM displays the following error message:

**Your installation CD-ROM coundn't be mounted. This probably means that the CD-ROM was not in the drive. If so you can insert it and try again.**

After some readings, I have tried with another command lines as follow:

```
title Run Ubuntu 16.04 Server
find --set-root /iso/ubuntu-16.04-server-amd64.iso
map /iso/ubuntu-16.04-server-amd64.iso (0xff) || map --mem /iso/ubuntu-16.04-server-amd64.iso (0xff)
map --hook
root (0xff)
kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/preseed/ubuntu.seed noprompt boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/iso/ubuntu-16.04-server-amd64.iso quiet splash --
initrd /casper/initrd.lz
```

and this time I failed to boot and the Grub4Dos displays the following error message:

**Error 62: The number of heads must be specified. The '--heads=0' option tells map to choose a value (but maybe unsuitable) for you**

What is the correct command lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISO file must be defragmented!!!

```
   title Run Ubuntu 16.04
find --set-root /ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso
map --mem /ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso (0xff) || map --heads=0 --sectors-per-track=0 /ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso (0xff)
map --hook
root (0xff)
kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso splash
initrd /casper/initrd.lz
```

Comment: Please explain what this is supposed to be.

Comment: this means that you MUST defragmentate your flash drive. ISO file must be single pease. 
I did it with Auslogics Disk Defrag Pro / there is portable version of this program.